# Rearranging a composition series

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm currently doing some research where I am trying to prove a property holds for all finite groups. I can show that the property holds for soluble groups.

My property is inherited by normal subgroups, and I ideally would like
to reduce the non-soluble case to an analysis of the (non-abelian) finite simple groups. So I would like to know:

Let $G$ be a finite non-soluble group, and let
$$
1=G_k \unlhd G_{k-1} \unlhd \dots \unlhd G_0 = G
$$
be a composition series for $G$.

Is it always possible to find such a composition series so that $G_k$ is not cyclic?

Thanks!

Comment: No, for example $\mathrm{SL}_2(5)$. The only normal subgroup is the centre, so $1\leq Z(G)\leq G$ is the only composition series.

Comment: That makes sense. Can we say anything about the smallest $G_i$ that contains a non-abelian finite simple group as a composition factor? For example, does it have to be almost simple or a central extension of an almost simple group or both?

Comment: I think what you need is the generalized Fitting subgroup. It is the central product of the Fitting subgroup, the largest normal nilpotent subgroup, and all subnormal quasisimple subgroups. Quasisimple groups are perfect groups $H$ such that $H/Z(H)$ is simple, i.e., central extensions of simple groups. The generalized Fitting subgroup $F^*(G)$ is normal and self-centralizing, and is the usual thing to reduce to when doing these sorts of proofs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll take a look.

Comment: Under your definition, $G_k$ is the trivial group, hence cyclic. Did you mean $G_{k-1}$?

Comment: Won't any semidirect product of cyclic and nonabelian simple group be a counterexample? Or more generally a non-trivial extension of cyclic group via nonabelian simple group?

Comment: @freakish: There isn't a nontrivial semidirect product.. Remember that the semidirect product would require a morphism $\phi\colon S\to\mathrm{Aut}(C_n)$, where $S$ is nonabelian simple; but the automorphism group of a cyclic group is abelian, so the morphism would be trivial and you get a direct product. And if it is a direct product, you can take the nonabelian simple group as the first term in the decomposition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah, you're right, nice observation.